# How to add ApplicationDbContext to dependency injection during runtime in my Blazor Server web app?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

as the titles says I have a Blazor Server web application, where if there isn't a database configured I redirect to a custom component Setup.razor, where the user must choose a database provider and insert the data for the app to make a connection string. After that the app successfully migrated the database, but I have an error, when I am trying to add the ApplicationDbContext to dependency injection during runtime.

Below is the example full code of .Migrate() function (for sql server) as well as adding the ApplicationDbContext to dependency injection:

```
string connectionString = $"Server={Server};Database={Database};User Id={Username};Password={Password};Encrypt=False;";

using (var db = new SqlServerDbContextFactory(connectionString))
{
    db.Database.Migrate();
}

using var scope = ServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
var services = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceCollection>();
services.AddOrUpdateDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

Below I will also include the code I am using for adding the ApplicationDbContext in Program.cs (In case the app is restarted, so it reads the data from LiteDB database):

```
var liteDbService = new LiteDbService<AppSettingsModel>(configuration);
var dbProvider = liteDbService
    .GetAll()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.KeyValueType == KeyValueType.DatabaseProvider);
var dbConnectionString = liteDbService
    .GetAll()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.KeyValueType == KeyValueType.ConnectionString);

if (dbProvider != null 
    && dbConnectionString != null 
    && dbProvider.DatabaseProvider != DatabaseProviderType.None 
    && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dbConnectionString.Value))
{
    switch (dbProvider.DatabaseProvider)
    {
        case DatabaseProviderType.SqlServer:
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(opt =>
                opt.UseSqlServer(dbConnectionString.Value));
            break;
        case DatabaseProviderType.MySQL:
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(opt =>
                opt.UseMySQL(dbConnectionString.Value));
            break;
        case DatabaseProviderType.PostgreSQL:
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(opt =>
                opt.UseNpgsql(dbConnectionString.Value));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

If it is possible, I don't want to restart the web application. So I want the dependency injection to update during runtime in that component.

Comment: What error are you getting? EF Core is used when the schema is known at the design time. If you are trying to apply ef core migrations at runtime, I doubt it will work at all.